# OOTB Publish Approval Workflow, is there some option to end on first Approval?

Tags: publishing, approval-process

I have sharepoint 2013. I have the OOTB list "pages". I have add the "Approval - SharePoint 2010" workflow to this list.

Now I have add the sharepoint group "approvers" to the field approvers.

How do I need to setup my workflow if I would like to finish/end the workflow after the first approval? I have for example 4 users in the sharepoint group "approvers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution: You need to uncheck the option "Expand groups". In this situation there will be 1 task and not for each user a task. The first approver who approved the task, finished the workflow and the item will be published.

Comment: Great solution Kha, simple and clean, I didn't think about it. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the workflow in SPD and customize the action.

[Here's a similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c86fb4ec-f08d-4de7-be6d-a132de3b87e3/sharepoint-workflow-end-on-first-rejection?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) but with the opposite (to cancel on first rejection)

And have you checked [this codeplex project](http://sharepointwf.codeplex.com/) ?

It provides a second association form page where you can select additional options such as:

- Approvers
- Due duration (days)
- Option to end on document change
- **Option to End on First Approval**

Comment: thank you..I have added a action in the OOTB workflow to end the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for anyone using SP2013:

In SP 2013, unchecking "Expand Groups" does not solve the problem. Multiple tasks are still created, and the workflow does not end until all approvers have completed their tasks.